# Override viewlet to be less pervasive

Tags: plone

I'm using a 3rd party product that provides a viewlet with an overly pervasive context of `plone.uuid.interfaces.IUUIDAware`, so it's effectively appearing on everything. I'd like to override this to restrict it to specific content types on my site.

I've tried adding the following declarative to both `configures.zcml` and `overrides.zcml` in the site package:

```xml
<browser:viewlet
    name="other.product.viewlet"
    for="my.site.interfaces.ICustomContentType"
    manager="plone.app.layout.viewlets.interfaces.IAboveContentBody"
    class="other.product.ViewletClass"
    template="browser/copy_of_product_viewlet.pt"
    layer="my.site.interfaces.ISiteLayerMarker"
    permission="zope2.View"
/>
```

However, it doesn't seem to replace the one provided by the product (I'm not sure how to refer to the template in the product from the site package override, so made a local copy).

Answer (score 0):

Use a convenient `configure.zcml` instead of `overrides.zcml` and add the layer-attribute to bind the viewlet to your product's interface.

See also:
http://developer.plone.org/views/more_view_examples.html

Comment: Tried this in both `configure.zcml` and `overrides.zcml`. It added the custom viewlet for the specific class bound to a site-package defined layer (so now there are two, including the one provided by the other package), and didn't remove the original from all other `IUUIDAware` objects. I've updated the question to show the layer binding.

Comment: Sadly, that hyperlink doesn't work anymore; it suffers an _(evil,_ if you ask me) catch-all redirection to the Plone 6 documentation root. It can be found in the web archive, though: https://web.archive.org/web/20130313132841/http://developer.plone.org/views/more_view_examples.html